# comprobar valores de un hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap

tengo una duda respecto a como retornar un objeto que está dentro de un hashmap:

```
empleado = new HashMap < String, Empleado > ();

empleado.put(empleado1.getNombre() + " " + empleado1.getApellido(), empleado1);
empleado.put(empleado2.getNombre() + " " + empleado2.getApellido(), empleado2);
empleado.put(empleado3.getNombre() + " " + empleado3.getApellido(), empleado3);


public static Empleado dameEmpleado(String nombre) {
    //Me debería retornar el empleado cuyo nombre y apellido paso por parámetro

    // Al no ser un array, no deja iterar  
    for (Empleado dato: GestionTareas.empleado.containsKey(nombre)() {

            return objetoEmpleado;

        }

    }
```

Lo que necesito es que me retorne el objeto empleado que tenga como clave en el hashmap el nombre que paso por parámetro. El bucle for no funciona con empleado.ContainsKey("nombreyapellido") porque no es iterable.

dameEmpleado() me debe retornar un objeto y el bucle for que recorre las claves de mi hashmap de empleados no retorna un objeto sino un boolean ( true si existe esa clave, false si no),por ejemplo si quisiera obtener el objeto correspondiente a la clave "Juan Gomez" deberia recorrer el hash buscando esa String. Para eso utilizo empleado.containsKey("Juan Gomez) pero este metodo me retorna un boolean y yo lo que quiero es que me retornen el objeto correspondiente a "Juan Gomez" para poder asignarlo a un arraylist de Tarea que solo permite empleados del hashmap

Answer (score 2):

Usa el método `get()` del `Map`, ese método recibe la llave y devuelve el objeto asociado o null si no existe.

```
public static Empleado dameEmpleado(String nombre) {
      
       return empleado.get(nombre);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando la respuesta de **Lobos** como correcta. Agrego que falta explicar bien el cómo funciona el `get` del `HashMap`.

1. Nota que al agregar dentro del `HashMap` esta se almacena mediante `clave` = `valor`.
2. La `clave` es quién va a ser almacenada dentro del `HashMap` para que esta haga referencia a tu `valor` por lo tanto según tu código tu `clave` es `Nombre + " " + Apellido`.

Por lo tanto en:

> public static Empleado dameEmpleado(String nombre)

debes verificar que `nombre` corresponda a una `clave` que tienes asignada dentro del `HashMap`, para que el `get` funcione correctamente.

Comment: Justamente quiero verificar que el String corresponda a una clave de mi hashmap y si es asi me retorne el objeto correspondiente a esa clave...